# OctoberCMS BackendAuth::getUser() return NULL

Tags: octobercms

The problem:
**Try to get current authenticated user in backend** (an administrator with some permissions), OctoberCMS platform.
I extended a plugin by a custom plugin ( in *boot()* method) and **I want to remove a sideMenuItem** from a menu when a user don't have permission to access it.
(I successfully made this - user can't access that item (Access denied) - but I want to remove that item from sideMenu).

Following code is in MyPlugin in that I want to extend OtherAuthor plugin.

```php
public function boot()
    {
        /** Extends plugin */
        $this->otherAuthorPluginExtend();
    }


 public function registerPermissions()
    {
        return [
            /** Permissions for accessing sidemenuItems from OtherAuthor plugin */
            'author.plugin.plugin_access' => [
                'roles' => ['Developer'],
            ],
        ];
    }

public function otherAuthorPluginExtend(){

//>>>THIS NOT WORK
        $user = \Backend\Facades\BackendAuth::getUser();
var_dump($user);

    /*this hide sideMenu item based on permission level*/
          if(array_key_exists('author.plugin.plugin_access', $user->permissions)) {
    //>>>THIS WORKS FINE, but for all backend users
            Event::listen('backend.menu.extendItems', function ($manager) {
                $manager->removeSideMenuItem('OtherAuthor.Plugin', 'Plugin', 'sideMenuItem');
            });
          }
    
      //>>>THIS WORKS FINE
    /*this restrict access to that page from sideMenu*/

        \OtherAuthor\Plugin\Controllers\SideMenuItemController::extend(function ($controller){
            $controller->requiredPermissions = ['author.plugin.plugin_access'];
        });
}
```

Why the $user get NULL?
Is another way to access it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is `event` is called once all plugin registered and user session started so, what you need to do is push `your conditional check code inside event callback`.

> In this way you can get the current backend logged-in user. `if you try to put the current user code outside maybe it's possible that the **session is not initialized yet**.

Your code should look like this.

```php
public function boot()
{
    /** Extends plugin */
    $this->otherAuthorPluginExtend();
}

public function otherAuthorPluginExtend(){

    // here you can not get user
    // $user = \Backend\Facades\BackendAuth::getUser();

    \Event::listen('backend.menu.extendItems', function ($manager) {
        /*this hide sideMenu item based on permission level*/
        // inside event callback you can retrieve user
        $user = \Backend\Facades\BackendAuth::getUser();
        if(array_key_exists('author.plugin.plugin_access', $user->permissions)) {
            $manager->removeSideMenuItem('OtherAuthor.Plugin', 'Plugin', 'sideMenuItem');
        }
    });

    /*this restrict access to that page from sideMenu*/
    \OtherAuthor\Plugin\Controllers\SideMenuItemController::extend(function ($controller){
        $controller->requiredPermissions = ['author.plugin.plugin_access'];
    });
}
```

> Now everything should work as expected :)

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: That is very good answer. Thank you. Works like a charm.

 `\Event::listen("backend.menu.extendItems", function ($manager) {
                $user = \Backend\Facades\BackendAuth::getUser();
//now the user can be managed
// rest of code
}`

Comment: hmm, may be share some example code then I can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding user fetch inside 'backend.menu.extendItems' event

Comment: This must be the shortest answer, but no example/details was offered. 
Thank you, but Mr Satasiya answered very well above.